# Any way to use SPOOL SQLPLUS command using cx_Oracle, SQL client of Python?

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

Am trying to execute a SQL Script using cx_Oracle which roughly looks like

`SPOOL /tmp/test.log
SET echo ON
SET serveroutput ON SIZE UNLIMITED
BEGIN
    #SOME_PL/SQL_STATEMENTS
END;
/
SPOOL OFF`

where am trying to write result of PL/SQL statements into a file. I came to know that SQLPlus commands are not supported in cx_Oracle. Is there any way to use SPOOL using cx_Oracle?

Comment: what if you went the other way - using Python in your SQLcl (java based, modern SQL*Plus) script? https://blogs.oracle.com/letthesunshinein/sqlcl-running-pythonactually,-jython you'd have full access to SQL*Plus commands like SPOOL

Comment: Is Jython an option instead of Python ? If so I can put an example here.

Comment: Or why not simply use python's File Objects ?

Comment: @KrisRice Please do.

Comment: @KaushikNayak That option is there. Just want to explore other options as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to use `SPOOL` within **cx_Oracle**.

The problem is that `SPOOL` is **SQL*PLUS** specific command. It is not an Oracle SQL command. Therefore the actual spooling is handled on client side. When you do things like

```
SPOOL ON
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
COLUMN username FORMAT A20
```

all of there commands are **SQL*PLUS** commands, a local (client-side) commands and they are not being send to Oracle server nor changing the behaviour of Oracle session at all.

These commands are there only to manipulate the way how the output from Oracle server is going to be shown on screen (or written to file or printer in case of SPOOL).

You can identify a local command by the fact that it does not have to be ended with semicolon `;` (in most cases).

Full reference of **SQL*PLUS** commands can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve001.htm#SQPUG023